# A free alternative to Google Sites with better table formatting?

Tags: google-drive, google-classic-sites

I like Google Sites, but there one thing, which annoys me a lot and forces to look for an alternative, `table operations`.

I use this service to manage project data and that means a lot of tables. At the moment it takes too much time to move a row etc., so I wonder if there is another free website offering similar functionality and better table formatting?

I would like to have a version control if possible.

Comment: Would it make more sense to put your data in a Google spreadsheet and embed the spreadsheet in your site?

Comment: Good idea. I guess this is why Google doesn't put much effort in developing table tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Weebly](http://www.weebly.com/) might work for you, it's a website builder.

Answer (score 0):

Continue using Google Sites, just embed a Google Spreadsheet.